# Indexing a dataset if index not exist

Tags: indexing, sas

```
proc sql;
create index key on data (Date);
<other statement>;
quit;
```

I used to create index on a dataset use above syntax. But if `data` is already indexed, it will return error and will not execute `<other statement>`. How to ensure everytime `<other statement>` will be executed whether index `key` exists (if not exist, then create one)?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error on my end. SAS should support creating multiple indexes on a table. For simple index, the name of index should be the same with column name (`Date` with `Date` here), or SAS will report error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has a two part answer:

**Continuing Execution**

If you want `<other statement>` to run regardless of the outcome of the `CREATE INDEX` statement, then simply put the following statement after the `CREATE INDEX`:

```
RESET EXEC;
```

As you may notice in the SAS log, when SAS encounters an error in the SQL procedure, it outputs a line:

```
NOTE: PROC SQL set option NOEXEC and...
```

The `RESET EXEC;` tells `PROC SQL` to reverse `NOEXEC` back to `EXEC` and continue executing statements.

However, it would be best to program the step so that it is unlikely to produce errors in the first place:

**Check for presence of index**

To conditionally check for the presence of an index, we need to use the `DICTIONARY` tables.

```
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :idx
  FROM dictionary.indexes
  WHERE 
  libname = 'WORK'
  memname = 'DATA'
  AND upcase(indxname) = 'KEY';
QUIT;
```

This sets a macro variable `&idx`, which will take the value 0 (zero) if the index is not present or 1 (one) if the index is present.

- Libname - the library in which the dataset resides (always CAPS)
- Memname - the dataset name (always CAPS, regardless of how it is created)
- indxname - the name of the index (capitalisation according to how the index is created, used UPCASE to force to upper-case)

You can then use SAS Macro to conditionally execute the following statements based on the value of `&idx`.

Answer (score 1):

One trick for removing indexes is that you can do a sort with FORCE - then the dataset is sorted, and any index is removed.

```
proc sort data=<whatever> force;
  by <whatever>;
run;
```

If the dataset is very large this may not be optimal, but as you should be sorting a dataset before indexing it in general this is usually not costly.